# Как разделить список на 2 равных списка?

Tags: c, list

Я создал односвязный линейный список:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 2
#define top_range 100
#define M 100

typedef struct node
{
    char firm[M];
    char type[M];
    char color[M];
    int price;
    struct node *next; 
}node;

void new_node( node **head,  node **last) 
{
     node *current;
    if ((current = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node))) == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"No free memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else 
    {
        current->next = NULL;
        current->price = rand() % top_range;
        printf("Firm:");
        scanf("%s",current->firm);
        printf("Color:");
        scanf("%s", current->color);
        printf("Type:");
        scanf("%s", current->type);
        printf("\n");
            if (!(*head))
                *head = current;
            else
                (*last)->next = current;

            *last = current;
    }
}

void print_out( node *lst) 
{
     {
        while (lst)
        {
            printf("Price:%5d\nFirm:%5s\nColor:%5s\nType:%5s\n", lst->price, lst->firm, lst->color, lst->type);
            printf("\n");
            lst = lst->next;
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

}
int main()

{


    struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node *last = NULL;
    struct node *new_head = NULL;
    int i, pos;


    for (i = 0; i < N;i++)  
        new_node(&head, &last);

    printf("List - \n");
        print_out(head);








    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Как разделить этот список на 2 равных списка и вывести их?

Comment: Вам на словах или кодом? Просто пройтись по списку, и разделить в нужном месте.

Comment: В теории всё понятно.Но практика хромает.Напишите кодом пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я разделил списки на равные по **длине**. Если не то, то скажите.

```
node * half_list ( node * const head ) {
  node * j = head ;
  // элемент перед половиной списка
  node * prev = NULL ;
  // половина списка
  node * half = j ;
  // цикл списка по два элемента
  // а половину по одному
  while ( j ) {
    if ( j -> next )
      j = j -> next ;
    else
      break ;
    prev = half ;
    half = half -> next ;
    j = j -> next ; }
  // отрезаем у первого списка конец
  if ( prev )
    prev -> next = NULL ;
  // возвращаем остаток
  return half ; }
...

printf("1.List - \n");
    print_out(head);

new_head = half_list ( head ) ;

printf("2.List - \n");
    print_out(head);
printf("3.List - \n");
    print_out(new_head);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.Благодаря вам разобрался с темой списков и узнал немного нового из вашего кода